# Visible radio wave propagation

Tags: propagation

Has anyone actually seen a visible radio wave? If so please comment. I am just wondering if it has ever been recorded before. or if its something that was left out of NEETS or is maybe top secret.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and does not appear to be a valid question

Comment: Actually, Radio Astronomy is a means of visualizing radio waves.  Although you are not actually seeing the electromagnetic wave directly, you are seeing the color toned graphic image created to demonstrate intensity for given frequency bands.  I think this is a very effective method of visualizing radio waves.

Answer (score 8):

There are visible radio waves. We call them 'light'.

We can see a whole range of frequencies of these waves, translated by our brains into something we call 'colours'.

Answer (score 4):

By definition radio waves are not part of the visible electromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: can they propagate through a vacuum, could you see them if you added a dash of toner.

Comment: Yes. Check out this image from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum#mediaviewer/File:EM_Spectrum_Properties_edit.svg)

Comment: anyways there is an high voltage transformer out side my house and on a moist day i can see stray waves emitting from it.

Comment: thats a very familiar page, i like this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

Comment: she keeps a buzzing on a hot day and if i get close i feel like my head is going to explode. possibly some microwaves?

Comment: maybe in absence of a carrier wave, sound injected into a coil creates this microwave effect that i came across.